# Unexcpected output while trying to draw line in java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

This is my first GUI exercise. I am trying to draw a line using a for loop but for some reason I haven't figured out why I'm getting only its last dot (pixel). I guess `repaint()` does something different than what I thought but I can't figure out yet what it is.

here is my code:

```
 package com.mycompany;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class MousePanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener{

        int pointX, pointY, oldX, oldY;

        public MousePanel(){
            super();
            addMouseListener(this);   
        }

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mouse){


            // Tell the panel that we need to redraw things.
                oldX=pointX;
                oldY=pointY;
            // Get the location of the current mouse click.
                pointX = mouse.getX();
                pointY = mouse.getY();
            // Tell the panel that we need to redraw things.

                for (int i=0 ; i<50 ; i++)
                {
                    pointX ++;
                    repaint();

                }
                System.out.println("x:"+pointX+", y:"+pointY);

            }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            g.fillOval(pointX, pointY, 5, 5);
        }

        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent mouse){ }   
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent mouse){ }
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mouse){ }
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent mouse){ }

        public static void main(String arg[]){
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("MousePanel");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(640,400);

            MousePanel panel = new MousePanel();
            frame.setContentPane(panel);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

the
Java Code:

```
for (int i=0 ; i<50 ; i++)
            {
                pointX ++;
                repaint();

            }
```

Comment: you only need one time to call repaint you know, where is your paint method?

Comment: Repaints are not persistent if you are actively drawing, meaning what you previously had on the screen will be wiped out on repaint(). You need to paint all the previous points as well everytime you paint a new point.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm getting only its last dot (pixel).

That is all you paint in your paintComponent() method.

If you want all the ovals then you need to repaint all the ovals every time the paintComponent() method is invoked.

See [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for the two common ways to do this:

1. Keep track of all the objects to be painted in an ArrayList and then iterate through the List every time paintComponent() is invoked
2. Paint your objects to a BufferedImage and then just paint the BufferedImage in the paintComponent() method.

Comment: *"Paint your objects to a BufferedImage and then just .."* ..display the image in a label.  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson, That would make more sense in this case - don't reinvent the wheel :)

Answer (score 0):

The repaint will always draw the fixed end-state of the component..

And, since you request the repaint in a single callback, you will get the following

```
x=1
repaint 
x=2
repaint 
...
etc.
```

The repaint itself does not occur until you have finished the loop, and the next UI event can be processed (which is your repaint request). The 50 or so repaint requests are probably conflated into one, which again calls your paintComponent.

Now the paint see that it should paint a 5px oval using your current x value, and does so.

So you would probably replace the for loop with a single repaint request, and change the paintComponent to paint between oldX,oldY and pointX,pointY

Answer (score 0):

You are repainting the oval 50 times. I'm not very sure what you want to do. If you wish to fill an oval with a width/height of 50 pixels, you could update the method paintComponent

```
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    g.fillOval(pointX, pointY, 50, 50);
}
```

In this case the for loop is not necessary, only a repaint is enough.

If you want to draw a line, there is the method drawLine. I see you have the old pixels position stored so you could go for

```
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
       g.drawLine(pointX, pointY, oldX, oldY);
    }
```

Again, only a repaint is necessary and no loop. I've posted the code below

```
public class MousePanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

int pointX, pointY, oldX, oldY;

public MousePanel(){
    super();
    addMouseListener(this);
}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mouse){


    // Tell the panel that we need to redraw things.
    oldX=pointX;
    oldY=pointY;
    // Get the location of the current mouse click.
    pointX = mouse.getX();
    pointY = mouse.getY();
    // Tell the panel that we need to redraw things.
    repaint();
    System.out.println("x:"+pointX+", y:"+pointY);

}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    g.drawLine(pointX, pointY, oldX, oldY);
}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent mouse){ }
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent mouse){ }
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mouse){ }
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent mouse){ }

public static void main(String arg[]){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("MousePanel");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(640,400);

    MousePanel panel = new MousePanel();
    frame.setContentPane(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}